# Is this explanatory sentence properly added to the end of another sentence?

Tags: run-on-sentences

In the following paragraph, I am trying to say data collection has been performed using certain questionnaires, and in the end of the paragraph, I want to say the distribution of those questionnaires has been based on simple random sampling. Is the way I add the explanatory sentence to the end of the paragraph (in bold) correct?

> Collecting the information related to the study’s variables was done using Goldman’s standard questionnaire, incorporating 33 questions for measuring the variable of emotional intelligence and its 5 dimensions (self-awareness, self-adjustment, motivation, empathy, and social skills), and the questionnaire of Sherer et al., for measuring the variable of self-efficacy, incorporating 17 questions, **with the questionnaires being distributed among the members of the statistical population based on simple random sampling.**

Answer (score 2):

While your question is technically about the right way to incorporate that final clause into your sentence, I would actually advise that you break the sentence up for improved readability.

> Information related to the study's variables was collected using Goldman's Standard Questionnaire and the questionnaire by Sherer et al. Goldman's Standard Questionnaire has 33 questions which measure the variable of emotional intelligence and its five dimensions - self-awareness, self-adjustment, motivation, empathy and social skills. Sherer's questionnaire has 17 questions which measure the variable of self-efficacy. The questionnaires were distributed among the members of the statistical population based on simple random sampling.

I've reworded a couple of sentences a bit. If you really, *really* must use a long sentence, the correct form would be

> with the questionnaires *distributed*

"being distributed" is a present progressive passive voice construction, which implies that the act of distributing the questionnaires is currently going on. In your example, that's not the case - you're talking about data collection that has already completed, so simply using the past participle "distributed" is what you need.

Comment: I cross-posted with you, and your answer is more complete and better than mine.

Comment: Thanks @Evelyn, and also - wow, how similarly do we think? :)

Answer (score 2):

The combined sentence as you have it is technically correct (except that "Collection of" is better usage than "Collecting," and you seem to be missing a comma in "Sherer**,** et al.").

But the first part is a rather complex sentence as it is, and I'd probably just give the bit about the distribution of the questionnaires a second sentence all of its own:

> The questionnaires were distributed among the members of the statistical population based on simple random sampling.

I might also break up the first part of the sentence for better readability:

> Collection of the information related to the study’s variables was done using Goldman’s standard questionnaire, and the questionnaire of Sherer, et al. Goldman’s questionnaire incorporates 33 questions for measuring the variable of emotional intelligence and its 5 dimensions (self-awareness, self-adjustment, motivation, empathy, and social skills). Sherer's questionnaire measures the variable of self-efficacy using 17 questions. The questionnaires were distributed among the members of the statistical population based on simple random sampling.